# difference between jquery validate plugin and ASP.NET MVC data annotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I am wondering what is the difference between validating Controls using JQuery Validate plugin and ASP.NET MVC DataAnnotations?

Appreciate your responses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JQuery Validate is a JQuery plugin for client side validations.

Up until MVC2 all the unobstruive ajax and validation targated ASP.NET AJAX library. but in asp.net MVC3 unobstruive ajax and validation targets JQuery and JQuery validate plugin.

see this video http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2011-Brad-Wilson-Advanced-MVC-3 by Brad Wilson where he talks about custom unbostruive validations.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC DataAnnotations is a best way to validate your controls as they can validate your inputs to client side and server side as well.

In MVC 3 you can also use RemoteAttribute to send a remote call to an action method.